# Thunder cloud problems

Tags: homework-and-exercises

In the problem
"On a cloudy day,a man hear a thunderclap 5s after seeing a lightning flash.How far away is the man from the source of thunder."
Explainer said that
the difference of the time taken to travel sound and the time taken to travel light is 5s.
I cant understand about it.
Explain me.

Comment: What is the speed of light? What is the speed of sound? How are thunder and lightning related. And it is a good rule of thumb...

Answer (score 1):

Heyho,

to keep it short, one can see the lightning flash nearly immediately after the thunder since the speed of light is very fast ($300.000 \frac{km}{s}$, yet it takes a while until u can hear the thunder, because the velocity of sound is only about $343 \frac{m}{s}$, so if it takes 5 seconds for you to hear the thunderclap after seeing the lighning flash that means the sound was travelling for 5 seconds with a speed of $343 \frac{m}{s}$ resulting in a distance of $x = 5s * 343 \frac{m}{s} = 1715m \approx 1.7 km$.

That means the thunder is approximately 1.7 km away from you.

Sincerely

Comment: why are they difference the two times

Comment: because light is a lot faster than sound.
$speed \; of  \; light = 300.000.000 \frac{m}{s}$, while $speed \;  of \; sound = 343 \frac{m}{s} $ that means light is approximately 874.000 times faster than sound, and therefore needs only $\frac{1}{874000}$ of the time for the same distance.

Comment: If I add this two times interval,will it be equal 5s?

Comment: I don't understand your question sorry :(

For every second that passes until the man hears the thunderclap after seeing the flash, the thunder will be 343 meters further away.
So if he hears the thunderclap after 1 second, that means the thunder is 343 meters away.
If he hears it after 2 seconds, the thunder is 686 meters away, if he hears it after 3 seconds the thunder is 1029 meters away, if he hears it after 4 seconds, the thunder will be 1372 meters away and if he hears it after 5 seconds it will be 1715 meters away :)
$seconds \times 343 = distance$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little story will help.

In a country far, far away, and a long long time ago, the king died in battle. His generals sent messengers to the castle. One messenger rode the swiftest horse in the country called Lightning; it was so fast, it arrived almost as soon as it left, as it was able to cover 300 km in one millisecond. The second messenger rode a donkey named Thunder. Thunder was fast, but much slower than Lightning, traveling a mere 330 meter per second.

Because Lightning was so fast, he arrived at the castle first, and told the queen the sad news. When Thunder arrived much later, he found the city already in mourning.

We can use the difference in speed between Lightning and Thunder to figure out how far away the battle was. Let's call that distance D; the speed of Lightning $v_L$ and the speed of Thunder $v_T$.

Time taken by Lightning:

$$t_L = \frac{D}{v_L}$$

Time taken by Thunder:

$$t_T = \frac{D}{v_T}$$

The difference

$$t_T - t_L = \frac{D}{v_T} - \frac{D}{v_L}\\
D = \frac{v_L\cdot v_t}{v_L-v_T}\left(t_T-t_L\right)$$

When $v_L>>v_t$ this can be rewritten as

$$D = v_t\left(t_T-t_L\right)$$

Which is the result you were having trouble understanding.